# How to import specific Widget to another file

Tags: flutter, import, widget

I have created this date picker

```
Widget completedDatePicker() => Column(
children: [
  buildDatePicker(),
  confirmButton(),
  ]);
```

and I want to import just this widget to another file like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vb5sQ.png)

how do I import it and should I use Stack class to make it like the picture above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it, so I use class to return widget to another file like this

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget

{
  final Color bgColor;
  final String title;

  const TestWidget(Key key,this.title, this.bgColor) : super(key: key);
return (widget here);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can move it to its own class with its own context(basically as a stateful or stateless widget) And then you can use it anywhere you need it.

Comment: and how do I import it just the date picker at the bottom of the screen without extra white screen